# Deducing a Function from a Series of Points

Tags: functions

This is for a computer science thing, but I'd like to understand it from the raw mathematics.

Let's say we have a randomly selected function. It could be linear, logarithmic, exponential, or a sine wave, possibly with random efficient (and yes, we know it will be one of these 4 ahead of time). So you might have $y=x^2$, or $y=3x^2$. (These are not in stone, just examples; if possible I'd like a general solution for any collection of known functions.)

Now, given a series of points along that function, I'd like to guess which of the functions, in our collection, it is.

With 1 point, nothing can be predicted.
With 2 points, nothing can, also, be predicted. (I think)
But with 3+ points, we'll start to get a clearer and clearer picture.

What type of theorem, process, or even just Google search terms, should I look into find methods to solve this problem? (I'm not even sure how to tag this question-- I'm just starting out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space of all functions is much too large.  Most functions are wildly chaotic and you can't learn anything from even a large number of points.  The space of functions of interest to people depends sensitively on the population of people you are talking about.  You can always fit an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial through $n+1$ points.  Lagrange interpolation will tell you how.  If you know the form of the function but it has a number of parameters, function minimization will find the parameters.  Numerical analysis books will discuss these questions.